# The proof to the statistic estimate

Tags: statistics

Suppose we have
$$r=\frac{a_1a_2 \cdots a_m}{b_1b_2 \cdots b_n}$$
Relative error of each of $ai$ and $b_i$ is roughly the same and equals $\delta$. There is a theorem which says:

$\delta_r=\sqrt{3(n+m)}δ$ if $m+n>10$.
This is called $The$ $statistic$ $estimate$.

I do not know where this theorem come from and cannot find any proof. Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\log r=\log a_{1} + \log a_2 + \cdots \log a_m
- \log b_1 - \log b_2 - \cdots \log b_n$$
Now consider everything as functions of a parameter that may variate a bit, and differentiate:

$$\frac{dr}r =  \frac{da_1}{a_1} + \cdots \frac{da_m}{a_m} 
 - \frac{db_1}{b_1} - \cdots - \frac{db_n}{b_n}$$

The RHS is a sum of $n+m$ values that take values that are roughly $\delta$,
and

$$\left(\frac{dr}r\right)^2 =  \left(\frac{da_1}{a_1} + \cdots \frac{da_m}{a_m} 
 - \frac{db_1}{b_1} - \cdots - \frac{db_n}{b_n}\right)^2 \\=
 \left(\frac{da_1}{a_1}\right)^2 + \cdots \left(\frac{da_m}{a_m}\right)^2 
 + \left(\frac{db_1}{b_1}\right)^2 + \cdots + \left(\frac{db_n}{b_n}\right)^2 = (n+m)\delta^2
$$
Here, I supposed that sources of errors in every variable compensate, because they are independant and are close to 0, so the crossed products are small compared to the squares.

The condition "$n+m$ big enough" is here to make sure that those terms compensate.
I would not call this formula a theorem, but a good estimate.